# Sql Order by Case query with bit value not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tried the following

```
order by 

CASE @OrderByUnique
  WHEN '1' THEN asg.total_unique_groupcount
  WHEN '0' THEN asg.total_groupcount
END desc
```

And

```
order by 

CASE @OrderByUnique
  WHEN 1 THEN asg.total_unique_groupcount
  WHEN 0 THEN asg.total_groupcount
END desc
```

But it only works if I use an else, so for some reason in my case statement I can't match it to true(1) or false(0)

```
order by 
    CASE @OrderByUnique
      WHEN '1' THEN asg.total_unique_groupcount
      WHEN '0' THEN asg.total_unique_groupcount
    ELSE asg.total_groupcount
    END desc
```

My variable is declared at the top of my function as

```
ALTER function [dbo].[myFunction] 
(
     @user varchar(30)
    ,@double_entry_flag bit
    ,@OrderByUnique bit = 1
)
```

Comment: Try `WHEN @OrderByUnique = 1 THEN ... WHEN @OrderByUnique = 0 THEN ...` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @OrderByUnique bit = 1;

WITH Data (count1, count2) AS 
( 
    SELECT 1, 4
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 3
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 1
) 
SELECT * FROM Data
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderByUnique = 1 THEN count1 ELSE count2 END DESC
```

EDIT: Oh and btw, your first examples both work too. Just try to replace last line of my example by

```
ORDER BY CASE @OrderByUnique WHEN 1 THEN count1 WHEN 0 THEN count2 END DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY CASE @OrderByUnique WHEN '1' THEN count1 WHEN '0' THEN count2 END DESC
```

and you will get same results. So your problem is probably in something else...